# SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have that logout function:

```
logOut:
            function(){
            var url = "http://localhost:8181/logout?sessionid=" + $localStorage.session;
            console.log(url);
            $http.post(url);
            $location.path('/login');
```

and if I'll type

> http://localhost:8181/logout?sessionid=cb544aea20aa4747b16dbeb88ff2ea76

in my browser it returns **SUCCESS** and nothing else (for *$http.get(url)* there's same response). As I found it's not valid JSON format and because I have that error. But how can I parse that? I can't change it. This **WEB service** isn't written by me.

Comment: What isn't a valid JSON format? What even is the problem?

Comment: What are trying to achieve and what is the issue you are experiencing? It's not entirely clear from the provided text. One thing that is to note, is that when you type the URL in the browser, it executes a GET requets, and in your code you are performing a POST request. If you're getting different results between the two, that'd be why.

Comment: @DaveNewton — The response, `SUCCESS`, is not JSON. It's a problem because Angular is trying to parse it as JSON.

Comment: I don't know Angular, but https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses looks relevant.

Comment: @RonBrogan for get it's the same. on browser it reutns only the text SUCCESS and nothing else. it means that user succesfully loged out. but angular automatically trys to parse it as json and that's my problem. it loggs that error in console

Comment: Just pass an empty object to wherever the JSON is being parsed?

Comment: @nem — The internals of the Angular library? That's not very practical.

Comment: @Quentin I am not familiar with angular, this was more of an in-the-dark-suggestion :). Anyways, looks like **Bas van Stein** has an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force Angular **not** to parse it to json use:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'POST',
  transformResponse: [function (data) {
      // just return the data, no parsing
      return data;
  }]
});
```